# can't install SDL-1.2.15 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: sdl

Having real trouble installing SDL-1.2.15 on the latest version of Ubuntu.

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/multimedia/sdl.html

The install guide that comes with the tar file says that I need to start by calling the configure file.  Looking at the comments, this seems to be needed to create a makefile with which to compile the library.  So, as advised, I start by typing:

sudo ./configure

To which I get the following error message:

sudo: ./configure: command not found

Now, I've got Ubuntu set up to show executable files as red in the terminal window, and the configure file does not appear to be executable.  So I'm confused.  Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so many hours of googling have revealing the solution.  I needed to use:

```
sudo sh ./configure
```

The explanation as to why can be found here:

http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=8083&highlight=configure+command

```
 "`cd' to the directory containing the package's source code and type 
 `./configure' to configure the package for your system.  If you're 
 using `csh' on an old version of System V, you might need to type 
 `sh ./configure' instead to prevent `csh' from trying to execute 
 `configure' itself."
```

Still don't really understand what's being said even after further research.

Answer (score 0):

Comments to the other topic you created ([configure script throwing up gcc errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145488/configure-script-throwing-up-gcc-errors)) suggest that you were trying to run the script from a non-POSIX filesystem (from a Windows partition). Filesystems like FAT32 do not "know" about the executable bit, which is why the script refused to run.